# Modern (.NET 4.5.2) C# Joystick capture method? DirectInput or HID or something else?

Tags: c#, joystick

I'm having a hard tiem finding modern relevant C# information on capturing joystick data in VS 2015.  All the examples i see use outdated DirectInput or some third party app (SlimDX) that hasn't been updated from what I can tell since 2012.  Whats the current modern way to get basic joystick input in C#?

Comment: MonoGame has some input libraries, it is regularly updated.

Comment: The modern way is use whatever way the engine you are working with provides you, most of time new games don't design their own framework and work on top of something else (Unity3d, Unreal, ect.). How do you do it outside of a game engine? No idea, if I did I would have posted this as an answer instead of a comment. UPDATE: after some quick research it looks like the answer is you use DirectInput, but I will be following this question to see if it is something else.